# Portfolio Basics in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, portfolio

I'm looking for some basic tips on using a Portfolio object in MATLAB. I have a set of asset returns, say a1 a2 a3 a4, and a set of weights for said assets, w_a1 w_a2 w_a3 w_a4. Further, I have this information for multiple month time periods (i.e. the weights change every month, so each w_* represents a vector of weights). How do I use this information in Financial Toolbox's portfolio object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portfolio only works at a single time period. What you would need to do is instantiate a portfolio object inside another data structure that will capture dates.

Personally, I prefer the table object in MATLAB as it allows for disparate data types to be grouped together.

What you'll do is create a series of dates in a table

```
Variable=table;
Variable.Dates=[datetime([2015 1 1]); datetime([2015 2 1]); datetime([2015 3 1])]
```

Set up your portfolio object

```
p1 = Portfolio('assetlist', { 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'});
p1.InitPort=[ w1; w2; w3; w4 ]
```

Repeat for each time period and merge into the table array.

```
Variable.PortfolioAllocation=[p1;p2;p3]
```

Which will give you a variable array of portfolio objects.

```
Variable = 

   Dates       PortfolioAllocation
___________    ___________________

01-Jan-2015    [1x1 Portfolio]    
01-Feb-2015    [1x1 Portfolio]    
01-Mar-2015    [1x1 Portfolio]
```

You can subsequently iterate over this to run your simulations.